# Why are my images squished left into a single column?

Tags: php, html, filemaker

I'm new to the filemaker API. I'm trying to build a thumbnail page where the images pulled from the database are lined up in rows but instead they're in a single column. Ideally it wouldn't be a fixed number per row, but would change based on display settings. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php

     require_once 'fmview.php';
     require_once 'FileMaker.php';
     require_once 'error.php';

    $cgi = new CGI();
    $cgi->storeFile();
    $userName = $cgi->get('userName');
    $passWord = $cgi->get('passWord');

    $databaseName = 'costumehistoricalcollection';
    $hostName = '137.99.30.10';

    $layoutName = 'Listing';

    $fm = & new FileMaker($databaseName, $hostName, $userName, $passWord);

    ExitOnError($fm);
    $layoutList = $fm->listLayouts();
    ExitOnError($layoutList);

    class EmptyRecord {
        function getRelatedSet($relationName) {
            return array(new EmptyRecord());
        }

        function getField($field, $repetition = 0) {
        }

        function getRecordId() {
        }
    }

    $record = new EmptyRecord();

    $findCom = $fm->newFindAllCommand($layoutName);
    $findCom -> addSortRule('Catalog_Number', 1, FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND); 

    $result = $findCom->execute();
    ExitOnError($result);
    $records = $result->getRecords();

?> 

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="photo_black.css">
        <title>
            Virtual Historical Costume Museum
        </title>

        <script type = "text/javascript" src="client_libs/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <!--hide from incompatible browsers

        function switch_resulting_view(){

            if (document.forms[0].action == "recordlist.php"){
                    document.forms[0].action = "thumbnaillist.php";

                    document.getElementById("theView").innerHTML = "THUMBNAIL VIEW";
                }else{
                    document.forms[0].action = "recordlist.php";
                    document.getElementById("theView").innerHTML = "LIST VIEW";
                }
        }

    </script>


<body>
        <div id="wrapper"; style="width:100%">

          <div id="container"; style="width:100%">
            <!-- NEW NAV AND HEADER -->
                <?php   include("nav/header.html");   ?>

            <!-- PAGE BODY -->

             <!--   <div id="sidebar";style="float:left">
                <p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About the archive</li>
                    <li>Explore our Collection</li>
                    <li>Our Staff</li>
                    <li>Donate</li>
                    <li>Exhibitions</li>
                    <li>Contact</li> 
                </ul>
                <p>
                </div> -->

                <div id="content";>


                <div>
                <?php
                    $findCommand = $fm->newFindCommand("Listing");

                    $findCommand->addFindCriterion("Photo", "*");

                    $findCommand->addSortRule('Date CR', 1,FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND);

                    $result = $findCommand->execute();

                    if(FileMaker::isError($result)){
                        echo($result->getMessage());
                        return;
                    }

                    $records = $result->getRecords();

                    foreach ($records as $record){
                        $photo = $record->getField("Photo");
                        $thumbnail = $record->getField("Thumbnail");
               /*       $hist = $record->getField("History"); 
              /*        $desc = $record->getField("Description"); */
                        $cNum = $record->getField("Catalog_Number");

                        echo ("<tr>");

                        echo ("<td><a href = \"");


                        echo ($photo);
                        echo ("\">");
                        echo ("<img src= \" ");
                        echo ($thumbnail);
                        echo (" \"></a></td>");

                        echo ("<td><font color=\"white\">");
                        echo ($cNum);
                        echo ("<br><br><br>");
                /*      echo ($hist); 
               /*       echo ($desc); */
                        echo ("</font></td>");

                        echo("</tr>");


                    };
                ?>
            </div>



                </div>
           </div>
        <?php include("nav/footer.html"); ?>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I don't understand! How can I rewrite this to be an on-topic question? I thought I was very concise about my problem statement.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you want images to appear left to right and wrap around, then why do you have a new table row (<tr>) for every record? I also do not see an opening and closing <table> tags, so perhaps you need to update these to divs that you can float?

Comment: I'm working off my partner's code (she got into a car accident and won't be back until next week) and this is AWESOME, I hadn't noticed this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your HTML - missing attribute name.

Instead of

```
<div id="wrapper";width:100%>
```

it should be

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%">
```

And the same for the next tag

Comment: Thank you - missed this and it fixed the wrapper! However, the images are still only one column wide